# From arraybuffer to blob in Cordova

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, blob, arraybuffer

I'm trying to save locally (using LocalFileSystem) a picture (I retrieve from an URL with XMLHttpRequest) with Cordova. After much investigation, I have narrowed down the problem to one point: transforming a ArrayBuffer to a Blob. This is working with Chrome on Windows (the xhr.responseType being arraybuffer):

```
var blob = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
```

But it's not working with Cordova (2.9.0) on iOS (XCode iOS 6.1 simulator). Any idea?

Comment: Did you try using the FileWriter API of Cordove http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileWriter?
Many times things that work on the phone, don't work in the browser/simulator.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do. My XHR access returns me a ArrayBuffer. If I'm able to store it using a FileWriter without using a Blob, it's fine to me, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I'm not sure Cordova is able to do what I want yet, at least using a Blob. I found a solution using FileTransfer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure Blob is actually available on Cordova. I can't find any reference in the official documentation, even if some forum discussions mention it. Anyway, i don't think Cordova is able to save a JPEG file using a Blob as for the 2.9.0 version I'm currently using.

So I have found an alternative solution to store locally a file from an URL, using [FileTransfer](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer), thanks to GitHub Gists. I adapted a snippet I have found here:

https://gist.github.com/nathanpc/2464060

So thank you, Nathan...